# HttpClientFactory how to inject into class I have no control over core 2.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.1, httpclientfactory

I would like to use the new `HttpClientFactory` and I am having trouble setting it up.

I have the following  (Just noddy examples I put together to explain my point)

```
public class MyGitHubClient
{
    public MyGitHubClient(HttpClient client)
    {
        Client = client;
    }

    public HttpClient Client { get; }
}
```

Then in my `webapi.Startup` I have

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddHttpClient<MyGitHubClient>(client =>
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.github.com/");
       //etc..              
    });

    //NOW I get error "Class name is not valid at this point" for "MyGitHubClient" below

    services.AddSingleton<IThirdPartyService>(x => new ThirdPartyService(MyGitHubClient,someOtherParamHere));

    ///etc...
}
```

Third party constructor

```
    public ThirdPartyService(HttpClient httpClient, string anotherParm)
    {

    }
```

How can I use the `HttpClientFactory` when I have to call a class that I have no control over?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `AddSingleton` delegate used in the original question takes a `IServiceProvider` as a parameter argument. Use the provider to resolve the desired dependency

```
services.AddSingleton<IThirdPartyService>(sp => 
    new ThirdPartyService(sp.GetService<MyGitHubClient>().Client, someOtherParamHere)
);
```

Comment: thanks for your reply may be I am doing it wrong but I am gettig "Cannot convert MyGithubclient" to System.Net.Http.HttpClient"

Comment: Show the target class `ThirdPartyService` and its constructor

Comment: @developer9969 in the mean time check the update made based on the exception message.

Comment: added in question constructor

Comment: @developer9969 ok you were passing the wrong type into the constructor. I've made the necessary fix. Just call the client from the resolved dependency.

Comment: that works.Brilliant.Could you tell me if I need to should pass httpClientFactory inside "MyGitHubClient" rather then httpclient and also if I should make it static like the old days

Comment: No need. This new version was to get away from how it was done previously. The typed client above is a suggested model.

Comment: @developer9969 Check the following article for some good reading on the subject of Typed clients https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/httpclientfactory-named-typed-clients-aspnetcore

Answer (score 3):

In Startup.cs, `services.AddHttpClient();`

Extension method from https://github.com/dotnet/extensions/blob/master/src/HttpClientFactory/Http/src/DependencyInjection/HttpClientFactoryServiceCollectionExtensions.cs

In your class, add a `IHttpClientFactory` argument to your constructor.

If you want to use it in a class that doesn't take it, you need to create the `HttpClient` in a lambda in `Add*` and pass it in, or register `HttpClient` itself with that lambda and let DI pass it in

```
services.AddScoped(s => s.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>().CreateClient())
```

There's an example on the project GitHub:
https://github.com/dotnet/extensions/blob/master/src/HttpClientFactory/samples/HttpClientFactorySample/Program.cs

Comment: .thanks for your reply do you mean in "MyGitHubClient" add a constructor  like   public MyGitHubClient(HttpClientFactory clientfactory)
    {
        Client =httpclientFactory;  ??
    }

Comment: If you have control over the constructor, you should use a `IHttpClientFactory` argument on the constructor of that class. If you don't, and it takes an `HttpClient`, you need to create the `HttpClient` outside and pass it in.

Comment: I have control of "MyGitHubClient" but not of ThirdpartyService.So could you show me how I would use both.thanks

Comment: `MyGitHubClient` would have a constructor `public MyGitHubClient(IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory)`. `ThirdPartyService` would use `services.AddScoped<IThirdPartyService>(s => new ThirdPartyService( s.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>().CreateClient(), ...);` I'm typing on a phone so please excuse the code.